# IdentityServer3 MVC App with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I'm working on creating an MVC Web application backed by an API which uses IdentityServer3 and is compatible with Windows Authentication, but I'm losing my custom claims in the process.

To this end, I've deployed this project: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication

When I deploy it to IIS7 I cannot access either of two pages which display claims information until I turn on Windows Authentication. When I do this, I have access to the secure Web Page that shows claims and the API that shows claims. This is promising, but these displayed claims are SidGroups, and Default claims, respectively. I lose my custom claims.

Monitoring traffic in Fiddler, I notice that when hitting the protected claims page, there are two failed attempts which 401 followed by the successful attempt but which displays the wrong claims.

Has anyone encountered this? Does any one know the location of a working example of a Windows Auth compatible IdentityServer? I've looked over several tutorials which imply it's possible but I don't think they are compatible with IdentityServer3.

Comment: I forgot to mention that custom claims are visible out of the box. I only lose them when I deploy to IIS.